# retrieving an image from SQL database using PHP is not working

Tags: php, sql, database, web, phpmyadmin

the images column is named Spec_Photo and is of type BLOB, i uploaded one image using the insert tab in phpMyAdmin just to test retrieving it in my **php** code. but it didn't work 
here is my code:

```
Print "  <img STYLE='border: thin solid grey;left:00px;top:00px;'src='".$info['Spec_Photo']."' alt='idimage' width='110' height='110'> "
```

Comment: `$info['Spec_Photo']` must be an URL or an image enconded in base64.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain? If the image in the database is just uploaded, what should i do to retrieve it?

Comment: Read this http://pujanpiya.com.np/?q=node/25

Comment: do i need to create image table? can't i just use one image variable?